# Proving a subset of Vector space as a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that if the conditions of being a vector space is fulfilled by a subset of a vector space then it will be a subspace. And these conditions reduce to the three conditions that is:
Show it is closed under addition.
Show it is closed under scalar multiplication.
Show that the vector 0 is in the subset.
But how come these condition fulfill that additive inverse of a vector in the subset also exists in the subset.
I searched for this answer where it told that

$ -1.x=-x $

and hence additive inverse exists in the subset, but how can we assume that the field always contains $ -1 $ ?

Comment: If the field contains $a$ it must also contain $-a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But, for *any* field $K$, *every* element of $K$ has an additive inverse. That's part of the definition of field.

Comment: but is it necessary that both $ 1 $ and $ -1 $ exist in the field

Comment: By the definition of field, $1\in K$ and, again by the definition of field, every element of $K$ has an additive inverse. In particular, $-1\in K$.